# Share.RequestAsync() doesn't work on .Net MAUI in Windows 10

Tags: maui, maui-windows

On my .Net MAUI app, I need to use Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Share to share some text. I followed this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/share?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows

And this is my code:

```
    [ICommand]
    private async Task ShareAsync()
    {
        string text = $"Some text";

        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
        {
            Text = text,
            Title = "Calculation Results"
        });
    }
```

This works well on iOS and Android, but when I run it on `Windows 10` in Visual Studio, executing Share.RequestAsync() does not do anything. No exception is thrown. It just quietly passes this line... and nothing happens. Can this be fixed?

ADDED:

I created a sample project here:
https://github.com/DavidShochet/MauiApp1

Comment: I've got similar issue with `ShareFileRequest`. It used to work fine couple weeks ago, but now the share window pops up after firing `Share.RequestAsync` but no sharing options are available. Instead there is only a message: "This app can't share tight now". 
The same code works fine on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully triggered the `share window` via a button with `ICommand` in **Windows 11** like below:

```
public ICommand Mycommand { private set; get; }
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Mycommand = new Command(


     async() =>
     {
         string text = $"Some text";
         await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest

         {

                    Text = text,

                    Title = "Calculation Results"

                });
            });

     BindingContext = this;
}
```

And this should work as expected in `Windows` or other platforms. I would suggest that you can upgrading your VS to the lasted one. My VS version is `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current  Version 17.3.6`

**Update:**

The `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Share` doesn't work in `Windows 10` ,however it works in `Windows 11`. You can raise a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) in Github.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I use my code not from page's code-behind, but from the PageModel, as my app uses MVVM. I do have the latest version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What is your Operating System for your machine? Mine is Win11 E. Also, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: I added the project to my original question. I have Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating workloads. It fixed file sharing issue in my case.

PowerShell command line: `dotnet workload update`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work for me.